# Preg_replace replace the whole string instead of the first capturing

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, pcre

I'm looking help to resolve a problem I face with the preg_replace php function.
I made a Regex to match acronym, abreviation, ... Some of them uses dash or dot to separate letters, some don't.

```
\p{Lu}+(\p{Zs}?[.-]\p{Zs}?){1,10}
```

My purpose is to replace dash and dots with # , and I'm trying to use :

```
$re = '/\p{Lu}+(\p{Zs}?[.-]\p{Zs}?){1,10}/i';
$str ='normal text C.G. P- U.T.O .K.L. another normal text';
$subst = '${1}#';
$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);
```

In my understanding this should replace the first capturing group (a dash or a dot) and replace it by a #. But in fact, it replaces the letter.

For instance, in this string *C.G. P- U.T.O .K.L.* I expect to have *CGPUTOKL*, but in fact I have  *.#. #- #.#.# .#.#..*

You can access to all this on : https://regex101.com/r/gkeGiw/4.

Could you tell me where I'm wrong (and why) ?

Thank you in advance,

Regards,

Charles

Comment: Well you are replacing the whole matched string by reinserting the first capturing group `${1}` and then adding a `#`. You should capture your letters into a group, not the dot/slash. What do you try to accomplish by the `{1,10}` repetition?

Comment: Why using `\p{Lu}` (Uppercase letter) with `/i` modifier (case insensitive)? If you want only uppercase, use `\p{Lu}` without `/i` or if you want mixt upper and lower use `\p{L}` without `/i`.

Comment: What is the expected result for the whole string?

Comment: Hi everybody. Thank you for your coments. Sebastian, I just want to limit the acronym to 10 letters. Toto, you are right, it's useless, I just forgot to delete /i. The expert result is to turn  C.G. P- U.T.O .K.L. I  into CGPUTOKL.

Answer (score 0):

You need `preg_replace_callback`. As @SebastianProske said, you were capturing the bit you don't want. However, you can't just capture the bit you do want, inside a repeating pattern, because the last match overwrites all previous ones, so you'd only get the last letter of each one. You should match the entire acronym, and then scrub the match. This assumes a minimum of 2 letters per abbreviation:

```
$text_abbreviation_normalised = preg_replace_callback(
    '/\p{Lu}(?:(?:\p{Zs}*[.-]\p{Zs}*)?\p{Lu}){1,9}(?:\p{Zs}*\.)?/',
    function($matches) {
        return preg_replace('/\P{Lu}+/', '', $matches[0]);
    },
    $text
);
```

https://regex101.com/r/gkeGiw/7 for the explanation.

It's technically possible to do that without a callback but the regex would be *hideous*.